# Wordpress login - Already logged in?

Tags: wordpress, authentication

I recently upgraded to Wordpress 5.3 with PHP version 7.2.24.  After a couple hours Wordpress appears to log me out (permission based pages and widgets are not displayed). When I select to login it presents the normal Wordpress login page where I enter my username and password. When I click login the site redirects me to a page"
https://example.com/login-2/?redirect_to=https%3A%2F%2Fexample.com%2Fwp-admin%2Findex.php&action=confirm_admin_email

This page indicates that I am already logged in.

If while logged in (not waiting for the session to expire) I log out and try to login the same thing happens, it redirects me and says I'm already logged in.

After the redirect I am logged in, the issue is it is confusing users and one of the plugins we use shows users logged and until the plugin refreshes (with AJAX) it shows that I am logged in multiple times.

This happens to all users.

- I have cleared my cookies.
- I have checked functions.php in my parent and child themes for
  anything related to cookie expiration.
- I have looked for a plugin related to persistent logins.
- I and checked and recreated my .htaccess

Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: This is not exactly fit for Stackoverflow. But it does look like a possible plugin issue.

Comment: Try a different browser? (And yes, this kind of question seems off-topic for this site.)

Comment: Thank you,  same issue with another browser - I am removing plugins on at a time.  I will post the question on another site.  I just saw many other similar questions in a google search so I figured I would post here.